# Duplicate Symbols when using multiple Native Extensions

Tags: ios, air, air-native-extension

I would like to use more ANE in my Adobe AIR 3.7 iOS Project, but when I compile, it says, the ContextFinalizer, and ContextInitializer symbols are duplicated. I think, more of my ANE-s use  same named CI, and CF, but they are not opensourced, so I can't rename them. Any idea to hide the symbols (FlashBuilder 4.7 has a modul for this, but I use 4.6). Any workoround? Please Help me guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you'll need to use a version of the AIR SDK > 3.4 and compile on the command line. 4.7 has the option built in to select this, but previous version of flash builder do not.

You need to add the option: **‑hideAneLibSymbols yes**, for example:

```
adt –package 
    -storetype pkcs12 
    -keystore cert.p12 
    -hideAneLibSymbols yes
    -extdir anes
    myApp.air 
    myApp.xml 
    myApp.swf
```

More information on the adt command can be found [HERE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-7fff)

Comment: @Michael- I am trying same thing but it give me error "no such files local _filepath/-hideAneLibSymbols". Any idea how can I fix this issue ? I am using Flex 4.7 and AIR SDK version is 17.

Comment: Are you missing a space character there?